# Are there variations in the value of goods sold?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

Are there variations in the value of goods sold or traded in the frontier versus a city like Boston or New York?

Furthermore, are goods worth different amounts when selling to a peddler on a cart versus a peddler in a brick-and-mortar store?

Basically: is it more advantageous to sell goods at certain locations over others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Goods seem always to fetch the same price regardless of where you sell them.

I just tested this in the frontier and in Boston. A frontier peddler in a traveling cart offered me £3332 for all of the goods I was carrying (mainly bobcat and elk parts). A peddler in a cart in Boston offered me £3332 for the same haul. The shopkeeper in a brick and mortar store in Boston offered me £3332 as well.

---

#### Update

There *are* variations in the value of goods sold once you unlock the ability to sell goods via your own convoys. Thanks to aviangentile for pointing this out - I hadn't realized I could do that.

Comment: It should be noted, however, that selling prices do change when selling goods via convoys.

Comment: @aviangentile, what do you mean about selling goods via convoys? Are those the peddler carts in the frontier? (Or perhaps there's something in the game I haven't encountered yet.)

Comment: It believe it's unlocked when you get full control of Conner and the Homestead. The game makes you go through a simple tutorial of how convoy management works.